# NEXT_PUBLIC can't work with firebase-messaging-sw.js

Tags: firebase, webpack, firebase-cloud-messaging, next.js, google-sheets-api

I created a `.env.local` like this

```js
NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_API_KEY=xx-xx
NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN=xx.xx.com
NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL=https://xx-xx-xx.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app
NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID=xx
NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET=xx.xx.xx
NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID=xx
NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_APP_ID=x:xx:xx
NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MEASURMENT_ID=G-xx

NEXT_PUBLIC_SPREADSHEET_ID=xxx
NEXT_PUBLIC_SHEET_ID=xx
NEXT_PUBLIC_CLIENT_EMAIL=xx@xx.xx.xx.x
NEXT_PUBLIC_PRIVATE_KEY=-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nxxxxx\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n
```

Note: **Google Spreadsheet working so fine**
and my `firebase-messaging-sw.js` like this

```js
/* global importScripts, firebase */
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.6/firebase-app.js')
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.6/firebase-messaging.js')

firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  databaseURL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
  projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
  measurementId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MEASURMENT_ID,

})

firebase.messaging()
```

Firebase service worker shows me an error
[image]

This guy in yellow is a `console.log(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_API_KEY)`
This means that `next_public_` is good so far, But why is the `firebase-messaging-sw.js` not reading it.

I think the problem is that I did something to the config of the webpack

```js
module.exports = {
  webpack: (config, options) => {
    config.node= {
    // Some libraries import Node modules but don't use them in the browser.
    // Tell Webpack to provide empty mocks for them so importing them works.
    ...config.node,
    fs: 'empty',
    child_process : 'empty',
    net : 'empty',
    tls: 'empty',
  }
    return config
  },
};
```

But this is necessary to make google-spreadsheet work, without this config I can't use spreadsheet.

One more thing, **When I replace `process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_API_KEY` with the actual values, Everything is fine**

Comment: See if this answer solves your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66558307/11838606