# Environment variables not available to the client

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am doing the approach as instructed here:
https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/environment-variables

My `.env.local` file is as follows (vars censored):

```
GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT_FEDERATED="**************"
FIREBASE_API_KEY="**************"
FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN="**************
FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL="**************"
FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID="**************"
FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET="**************m"
FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID="**************"
FIREBASE_APP_ID="**************"
IOS_APP_ID=**************
IOS_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER="**************"
NEXT_PUBLIC_SECRET_KEY=**************
```

and my `next.config.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
    poweredByHeader: false,
    reactStrictMode: true,
    env: {
        GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT_FEDERATED: process.env.GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT_FEDERATED,
        FIREBASE_API_KEY: process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY,
        FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN: process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
        FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL: process.env.FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
        FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID: process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
        FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET: process.env.FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
        FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID: process.env.FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
        FIREBASE_APP_ID: process.env.FIREBASE_APP_ID,
        IOS_APP_ID: process.env.IOS_APP_ID,
        IOS_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER: process.env.IOS_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER
    }
};
```

I am instantiating the firebase instance with those variables and it prints out fine on the server, but on client they are all `undefined`
So my `firebase.ts` file is like:

```
import fb from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/database';

// firebase Config
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY,
    authDomain: process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    databaseURL: process.env.FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
    projectId: process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: process.env.FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
    appId: process.env.FIREBASE_APP_ID
};

console.log('process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY : ', process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY);
console.log('firebase config : ', firebaseConfig);
const firebase = !fb.apps.length ? fb.initializeApp(firebaseConfig) : fb.app()


export default firebase
```

Ouputs from server :
[image]
And outputs on the client:
[image]

Am I missing something or doing anything wrong?
As a result, I cannot use my firebase instance and I continuously get this error:
[image]

EDIT:
Looks like for variables to be available to the client, they need to be pre-pended with `NEXT_PUBLIC_` in the env file (and this was my case as well)

Comment: Did you try to restart the server? You code seems fine and it should work, although you are mixing 2 different approaches, old one (that referenced with your link https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/environment-variables) and the new one with `.env` file (https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables)

Comment: As referenced by @Danila, I'd recommend you expose environment variables to the browser using `NEXT_PUBLIC_` prefix.

Comment: I tried restarting. I also tried with the public variables. still no result

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Next.js 9.4 or above, you can use the newer approach of adding environment variables (see [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables)). You can remove variables from `next.config.js`.

Comment: hi Nikolai and thank you for your response. I started with that, but it doesn't do the trick

Comment: @DanutPralea, it seems you're confusing which variables should be public / private. Just add variables to your `.env`. If you want make them public add prefix `NEXT_PUBLIC_`. You shouldn't expose your firebase / database API keys to public and make calls to DB from the client side, unless you don't mind others use the leaked API credentials too. Use server / Next.js API routes to connect to DB.

Comment: I actually just did that (use `NEXT_PUBLIC_` prepending) and it does work. but yes, it feels unsecure and I'm pretty sure they can be intercepted. how else can I do it though?

Comment: Move the database calls to an [API route](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction), and call the API route from the client. This way you don't need to expose the env var to the browser.